# Removing NAs when multiplying columns

Tags: r

This is a really simple question, but I am hoping someone will be able to help me avoid extra lines of unnecessary code. I have a simple dataframe:

```
Df.1 <- data.frame(A = c(5,4,7,6,8,4),B = (c(1,5,2,4,9,1)),C=(c(2,3,NA,5,NA,9)))
```

What I want to do is produce an extra column which is the multiplication of A, B and C, which I will then cbind to the original dataframe.

So, I would normally use:

```
attach(Df.1)
D<-A*B*C
```

But obviously where the NAs are in column C, I get an NA in variable D.  I don't want to exclude all the NA rows, rather just ignore the NA values in this column (and then the value in D would simply be the multiplication of A and B, or where C was available, A*B*C.

I know I could simply replace the NAs with 1s, so the calculation remains unchanged, or use if statements, but I was wodnering what the simplist way of doing this is?

Any ideas?

Comment: How about  `D<- A*B*(C*!is.na(C) + 1*is.na(C))`  , which is a sneaky way around using `if` .

Comment: That would be great but I am afraid @CarlWitthoft that line of code doesn't work.

Comment: my apologies - I can't test/debug right now.  Can you tell me what error (or bad output) resulted?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft You code didn't calculate a product for any row where an NA was present. basically the same as `na.omit(A*B*C)`. Also although not explicitly asked, this will only account for NAs in C column. Not in others.

Comment: @Davy: yep, my apologies for being dense there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `prod` which has an `na.rm` argument. To do it by row use `apply`:

```
apply(Df.1,1,prod,na.rm=TRUE)
[1]  10  60  14 120  72  36
```

Comment: That's really interesting @James, I have never used 'prod' before - can I ask what the '1' is used for?  Also, if I have other columns in my dataset, but still only wanted to multiple A, B and C - is there a way of specifying the columns that I want it to find the product of?

Comment: @KatieT The 1 tells `apply` to work row-wise through the `MARGIN` argument. To limit the number of columns you would need to pass only the columns you want to use to `apply`, but this could be done inline: `apply(Df.1[c("A","B","C")],1,prod,na.rm=T)`

Comment: A related question @James... if I wanted to add the contents of those three columns instead of multiple them, is there an equivalent command to ‘prod’ that does that?

Comment: @KatieT `sum`. But in that case you might find that `rowSums` offers superior performance as you don't need to use `apply` with it.

Answer (score 2):

As @James said, prod and apply will work, but you don't need to waste memory storing it in a separate variable, or even cbinding it

```
Df.1$D = apply(Df.1, 1, prod, na.rm=T)
```

Assigning the new variable in the data frame directly will work.

```
> Df.1 <- data.frame(A = c(5,4,7,6,8,4),B = (c(1,5,2,4,9,1)),C=(c(2,3,NA,5,NA,9)))
> Df.1
  A B  C
1 5 1  2
2 4 5  3
3 7 2 NA
4 6 4  5
5 8 9 NA
6 4 1  9
> Df.1$D = apply(Df.1, 1, prod, na.rm=T)
> Df.1$D
[1]  10  60  14 120  72  36
> Df.1
  A B  C   D
1 5 1  2  10
2 4 5  3  60
3 7 2 NA  14
4 6 4  5 120
5 8 9 NA  72
6 4 1  9  36
```